# Is there a way to write part of script specific to a scene in unity3d

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, github

I have been searching for this from 2 to 3 days but unable to find any solution.

What I want exactly is, Treating every scene in unity as a branch functionality in github/bitbucket so that I can change some parts of line of code in a specific script to work differently for different scenes.

If I change a scene in game I want my game to load the script specific to this scene.

Ex: There is a script named, xyz.cs

If my game is playing scene1, some lines of code in xyz.cs changes.
If my game is playing scene2, some lines of code in xyz.cs changes may not be same as above scene lines.

## Basically the branch functionality of git to scenes(as branch) in unity in my game.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use branches in git? At first glance this seems like you are over complicating a problem.

Comment: If this isn't a question about version control and you want to have a similar script have slightly different implementations based on scene I would consider using an abstract class or interface and have a class that inherits it for each scene.

Comment: As mentioned above, a class called SceneAbstract with abstract methods (and implemented ones) then subclasses such as Level1:SceneAbstract.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the unity project in git is ok. But whether manage each scene in different branches, it’s depend on your needs and situations:

- If the `.cs` file in each scene need to be changed from time to time, you can manage each scene in different branches in git and it will help you to trace each versions for different scenes separately.
- If the `.cd` file is constant for each scene, you can manage different scenes in the same branch and use the way as Sam said in comment.

And if you managed each scene in different branches, you should keep entity of the `.cs` file (not part of script) for each branch. But you can change the `.cs` file based on another scene as you need.

Such as you want to change `xys.cs` file in scene2 based on the file `xyz.cs` in scene1, you can use below commands:

```
# On scene2 branch
git checkout scene1 xyz.cs
# the xyz.cs in scene2 branch will be same as scene1
# change the part you want to modify
git add .
git commit -m 'change part of xyz.cs file in scene2 branch'
```

Comment: Yeah thanks  but I am talking about the same scenario in game it self. If I change a scene in my game the new altered scripts should be loaded. I want git branching functionality in my game for scenes.

Comment: So your question is not related to use git to version control the unity but how to load the updated script after a scene changed (you can try scripting API for the issue). And you can remove the tag `version-control` in order your question can be better described and understanding.